# How to use assign TextView, Geocoder etc to variables in different classes other than main class?

Tags: android, android-context

While writing an Android App, when I use TextView in different class(MyClass) other than the main class,
I'm getting an error:

> The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyClass

Please tell me the point I'm missing.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the javadoc for `Activity` class and also http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html - the answers are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass` doesn't extend androids [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class, therefore you don't have that method available. So you have to get a reference to use it, preferably through a method argument *(never store a activity/context reference in a class member variable, it might result in a memory leak)*:

Small sample:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.doSomething(this);

        //...
    }
}
```

And in MyClass

```
class MyClass {
    public void doSomething(Activity a) {
        View v = a.findViewById(...);
        // do something here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `Context` of the application in the class where you want to use `findViewById()` or reference the `View (container)` that holds the view you want to find.